Logback Spring Boot configuration is not working on Azure
I have configured anonymizer for my logger:
--> logback.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
        <appender name="CUSTOM_CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>${CONSOLE_LOG_THRESHOLD}</level>
            </filter>
            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
                <layout class="util.CustomPatternLayout">
                    <anonymize>someFieldName</anonymizeJson>
                    <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
                    <charset>${CONSOLE_LOG_CHARSET}</charset>
                </layout>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <appender-ref ref="CUSTOM_CONSOLE"/>
        </root>
    <logger name="root" level="INFO"/>
</configuration

Locally, everything works fine, but when it is deployed to Azure in Docker container, it seems to ignore my logback file.
I tried to use this file for configuration with names: logback.xml, logback-spring.xml
I tried to specify configuration for docker container
-Dlogback.configurationFile=src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml
nd also with this in application.yml
I have application insights agent, maybe it is broking my logging?
logging:
  config: classpath:logback.xml

Locally, everything is ok but on Azure I got issues.

in your resource folder, just place your file with name logback-spring.xml, that's all you need. The <include part is not needed and is probably what is breaking during bootstrap

include is needed due to have default values for envs, etc.

@VolodymyrBurmus, can you please tell which version application insight you are using?

@SureshChikkam The version is 3.4.16

Can you please downgrade the version of applicationinsights-agent.jar to 3.2.4 and update once.


tried to use this file for configuration with names: logback.xml, logback-spring.xml I tried to specify configuration for docker container -Dlogback.configurationFile=src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml nd also with this in application.yml

logback.xml is not included in the final JAR file and specify its location externally when running the Spring Boot application.

When running the Spring Boot application, specify the location of the external Logback configuration file using the -Dlogback.configurationFile system property. This property tells Logback where to find the configuration file.

java -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/full_path/logback.xml -jar app.jar

Deploy the Spring Boot JAR without the logback.xml file included in it. Check that the logback.xml file is present in the same directory as the JAR file on the Azure server.
Add Dependencies:

In your  pom.xml, add the following dependencies for  Application Insights:

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-runtime-attach</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.18</version>
</dependency>

Configuration Logback:

Create a  logback.xml  file in your project (if you haven’t already).
Define your log format and appender.

Reference:
If possible try to use the below version for the java if the above approach is not satisfied.

applicationinsights-logging-logback 2.6.4


I have checked, my logback is included as it is in resources folder. Also tried to run the same container on the local without application insights, worked fine. Therefore the problem is somewhere between deployment and azure

Check the Logback configuration file is being included in the deployed package. Sometimes, deployment scripts or configuration files may inadvertently exclude certain resources.
